# Error message keeps coming back saying the array is not defined.

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing a website using Codeigniter. The structure site is simple, I have dynamic menu and content retrieving DB in Model. Then assign a method to call both of them in Controller.

I have that weird error message keeps coming back saying the array is not defined.

I can get tabPhotos, it contains datas.
View:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="photos">
        <?php echo "Count: ". count($tabPhotos); ?>
        <ul>
            <?php if (!is_array($tabPhotos) || empty($tabPhotos)) :?>
                <?php return null; ?>

                <?php foreach ($tabPhotos as $item) : ?>
                    <?php echo "Model: " . $item->url; ?>                   
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function loadMenu($file) {
    $data['tabMenuItems'] = $this->qdphoto_model->getAllMenuItems();
    $this->load->view($file, $data);    
}


public function loadCategoryPage($file, $category='Book 1') {
    $data['tabPhotos'] = $this->qdphoto_model->getAllPicturesByCategory($category, 'url, model');

    $this->load->view($file, $data);        
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what variable is returning undefined array? Would help debug.

Comment: could you please post the error message?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a `<?php else: ?>` in there? You're running a foreach loop after you returned NULL...

Comment: It looks I CAN'T pass one than one array in SAME VIEW file. ex: loadMenu('index_page'); loadCategoryPage('index_page');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I reading this correctly? if $tabPhotos IS NOT an array OR it is and it happens to be EMPTY then return null and continue to run the foreach loop with a mysterious endif following?

```
        <?php if (!is_array($tabPhotos) || empty($tabPhotos)) :?>
            <?php return null; ?>

            <?php foreach ($tabPhotos as $item) : ?>
                <?php echo "Model: " . $item->url; ?>                   
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Shouldn't it read this:

```
       <?php if (is_array($tabPhotos) && !empty($tabPhotos)) :?>
            <?php foreach ($tabPhotos as $item) : ?>
                <?php echo "Model: " . $item->url; ?>                   
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

no need for that return null statement.

Also, I believe you can return views as strings. If you want to load more than one view you can certainly load any fragment of your view as a string...

```
$string = $this->load->view($file, $data, true);
```

Please note that you should review this:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

See bottom. It says how to return as string, except that I am used to slightly different syntax thanks to custom controllers and such. Perhaps this example I provided is not accurate.